# Why is this XSLT to extract soap:Body also have soap:Header element values

Tags: xml, xslt, soap

I have a following soap envelope coming from client

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/03/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soap:Header>
  <wsa:Action>http://company.com/services/InterfacePoint/CallResponse</wsa:Action>
  <wsa:MessageID>uuid:85fafb9d-9ec0-4017-a367-4f9043812310</wsa:MessageID>
  <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/03/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
  <wsse:Security>
     <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-dc059677-19f6-4b2c-a69b-ec0dffc6b1db">
        <wsu:Created>2013-03-28T16:24:33Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires>2013-03-28T16:29:33Z</wsu:Expires>
     </wsu:Timestamp>
  </wsse:Security>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
  <TXLife xsi:schemaLocation="http://ACORD.org/Standards/Life/2 TXLife2.22.00.XSD" xmlns="http://ACORD.org/Standards/Life/2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  .
  .
  . 
  </TXLife>
 </soap:Body> 
</soap:Envelope>
```

I'm just interested in retrieving what is inside `soap:Body` and discard everything else. I wrote this `XSLT` to extract that

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="soap:Envelope/soap:Body">
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()" />    
  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This `XSLT` works fine when there is no header in soap envelope but if I apply this to above `XML`, it outputs values of header elements also, so the output it produces is:

```
http://company.com/services/InterfacePoint/CallResponseuuid:85fafb9d-9ec0-4017-a367-4f9043812310http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/03/addressing/role/anonymous2013-03-28T16:24:33Z2013-03-28T16:29:33Z<TXLife xmlns="http://ACORD.org/Standards/Life/2"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/03/addressing"
        xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
        xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://ACORD.org/Standards/Life/2 TXLife2.22.00.XSD">
.
.
.
</TXLife>
```

but I want output to be:

```
<TXLife xmlns="http://ACORD.org/Standards/Life/2">
.
.
.
</TXLife>
```

I don't care if other namespaces exist or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because there is a default template for text nodes which copies their content to the output.  To make your approach work you would need to suppress that by adding

```
<xsl:template match="text()" />
```

Now, provided your `soap:Body` has exactly one child element you should get a well-formed result, but it will still include the extra namespace declarations.

I would approach the problem from a different angle, using an identity template rather than copy-of.  XSLT 2.0 has the handy `copy-namespaces="no"` that you can use on `<xsl:copy>` to strip out un-necessary namespace declarations:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <!-- extract just the first child of the body -->
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/*[1]" />
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- identity template, but dropping namespace declarations not used
       directly by this element -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- drop xsi:schemaLocation attributes -->
  <xsl:template match="@xsi:schemaLocation" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for a neat response Ian. I want all the child elements also of the first child of body (child elements of TXLife). This `XSLT` outputs just `<TXLife xmlns="http://ACORD.org/Standards/Life/2"/>` and not its children. Can you please update your answer to include that

Comment: @Learner sorry, it was a typo - in the identity template it should be `select="@*|node()"` with trailing parentheses (not `node` without).

Comment: yeah, I figured after commenting but you're fast :). Thanks

Comment: Also, you said, this should be added `<xsl:template match="text()" />` to suppress but `XSLT` in your answer doesn't have that?

Comment: @Learner that template is what you'd have to add to your XSLT in the question to make that work, but my XSLT in the answer is a different approach entirely which doesn't require it.